# Changes in the UV Editor Not Flowing Over To 3D Viewport

Tags: 3d-view, uv-image-editor

When changing the vertices in the UV editor, the changes do not flow over to the 3D viewport, which displays something completely different.  I've tried deleting the faces and recreating them, checking the Stretching to see if there was some weird geometry that's twisting the image, but even when dragging the vertices in the UV editor to a completely blank area, it still shows the same warped texture in the 3d viewport, completely unchanged.  Can anyone please help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  Just found out that in my UV maps, it wasn't showing the second UV map I had created.  Thanks everyone for taking a look.

[image]